# Movie name - Man running from secret service agents that believe he is sent by Aliens

Tags: story-identification, clones

I'm looking for a movie name from late 1990s or early 2000s, about a man approached by secret service agents and placed in an scanning machine to find out if he is human or a clone sent by aliens.  The scanner freezes and the man escapes.  At the end of the movie

> the man reaches an area with a lot of trees where he see a capsule with his and her wife next to him dead and the nuclear bomb that was planted inside him detonates.

Anyone know the name of this movie?  There is a doctor in the movie that helps the man out and the scenes are mostly in the dark at night.

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117203/im-looking-for-a-movie-where-in-the-end-the-earth-is-destroyed-by-aliens (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 8):

**Impostor**

Based very loosely on the Philip K. Dick story of the same name.

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0160399/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1